# php - limit character string for loop

Tags: php

I have this in PHP:

```
$_chars = "0123456789ZXCVBNMASDFGHJKLQWERTYUIOP";

for($l = 0; $l<4; $l++){
    $temp = str_shuffle($_chars);
    $_charcode .= $temp;
}
```

I want it to only generate 4 characters. Currently It's generating 6. I've tried editing $l but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: `str_shuffle` returns the whole string, not just one character.  You're actually getting a 144 character (4 * 36) string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> `str_shuffle()` shuffles a string. One permutation of all possible is created.

You'll want to retrieve just one character from the shuffled string:

```
$_charcode .= $temp[0];
```

So, the code should look like:

```
$_chars = "0123456789ZXCVBNMASDFGHJKLQWERTYUIOP";

$_charcode = ''; // initialize the variable with an empty string
for($l = 0; $l<4; $l++){
    $temp = str_shuffle($_chars);
    $_charcode .= $temp[0];
}
echo $_charcode;
```

Output(example):

```
8VG6
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/53801)

Comment: lol :o) You edited your question to reflect the same content as I have (and a little bit more)

Comment: @bwoebi: Nope, I didn't. I just added the documentation bit (I can't create one excerpt  of my own). Also, look at the timestamp of the answers.

Comment: I seemed to me this way; sorry then ;-) The timestamp has a difference of 7 seconds, but you had also edited in the five minutes after creation while I hadn't…

Answer (score 2):

Docs (http://php.net/str_shuffle) state:

> str_shuffle() shuffles a string. One permutation of all possible is created.

it should actually generate `4 * strlen($_chars)` characters…

I assume you want:

```
$_charcode .= $temp[0]; // only one character
```